# Rails 3 Asynchronous External Programs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am designing a web service under Rails 3.2.8 which will execute external program for the users, the expected use case is:

1) User fill a form of parameters and submit the request

2) Rails execute a Matlab program based on user request. It would last a few minutes (less than 3mins) and generate a result file shows that the program is finished

3) During this process, redirecting user to a page shows "loading" status, and monitoring if the result file has been generated

4) Once the result file is generated, reload the page via AJAX and display the results.

Is there a "rails" way to do so? I did this before in JAVA SSH framework but pretty painful. What will be the tools I need? For example, do I need gems like backgroundjob
to manage the task queue? Or are there any "one-stand" gems can handle this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use Resque manage your background tasks, and something like Juggernaut (although it's deprecated, read the github page for the author's suggestion) to push the data to your client when the background job finishes.

Comment: You're probably all over this, but just in case: Be *very careful* with this kind of thing that you're not putting any unsanitised data entered into forms into your command-line, otherwise you're one 'rm -rf /*' away from disaster...

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will be very careful with my validation :). Also thanks to saverio, I am a little busy for the following two days, but will try your advice out asap and see if accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of several job queue providers. Examples include DelayedJob (simplest one ever, no additional pieces required), Resque and Sidekiq (much faster, but you need a small Redis server to use them).

A "job" will be (depending on the provider) a class or instance, which implements the execution. If it implies running something in the shell, you can do it like

```
%x[matlab command --options > output.ext]
```

(it's just an example, you can use string interpolation too: `%x[#{executable_name}]`)

Comment: Hi @saverio, I see DelayedJob is suitable for managing the queue. However, I did not see much monitoring function it provides. How do I know whether a task is end? Do I monitor the DJ database? For my use case, every time a user starts a task, a task folder with a timestamp will be built and all the result files will be generated in that folder. So the 'loading' page should also keep monitoring the folder. It seems we can not store the timestamp in DJ database right? (Matlab is painful since it seems unable to be redirect to STDOUT, or it would be a lot easier...)

Comment: Also another problem is that if we are using %x[] to start matlab, it will be regarded as completed by DJ once matlab program is started (instead of when the calculation is really completed)

Comment: Every queue system has its own features, if DJ has not enough monitoring, choose another, or just do something relevant after the `matlab` processing has finished.

Comment: The fact that matlab is going in background when executed (as when you write the command in a shell and you have the shell back) is the cause of your problem. You have to find out how to tell matlab not to fork out, otherwise no program, script etc, could ever start it and check for results...

Comment: Just noticed that maybe you need more info for the fork thing. If you could try octave or R, as they are open source, they may support better pipelining, so starting them as a batch process would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I kind figured out what to use during the whole process:

**1) User fill a form of parameters and submit the request**

Using the method from this rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model for server side validation and gem 'client-side-validations' to enable client side check.

**2) Rails execute a Matlab program based on user request. It would last a few minutes (less than 3mins) and generate a result file shows that the program is finished**

Using gem 'DelayedJob' for task management and 'ChildProcess' to start the Matlab program.

**3) During this process, redirecting user to a page shows "loading" status, and monitoring if the result file has been generated**

Monitoring child process as well as the existence of the result file to check whether the task is finished.

**4) Once the result file is generated, reload the page via AJAX and display the results.**

Using polling method from this rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes to update the result page. I am not using pushing although it would be more secure - as polling seems to be a more light-weighted solution and can meet my requirements.

Obviously this is not the best practice, but satisfies my needs and easy to implement. Thanks for all the comments and answers.